# Ignore specific types with auditd

Tags: linux, security, auditd

I've recently been playing around with auditd and trying to cut out some of what it is logging. Here is my audit.rules entry to log execve

```
# First rule - delete all
-D

-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S vfork
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S fork
```

This generates, for example, the following:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1384889328.421:128620): arch={redacted} syscall={redacted} success={redacted} exit={redacted} a0={redacted} a1={redacted} a2={redacted} a3={redacted} items={redacted} ppid={redacted} pid={redacted} auid={redacted} uid={redacted} gid={redacted} euid={redacted} suid={redacted} fsuid={redacted} egid={redacted} sgid={redacted} fsgid={redacted} tty={redacted} ses={redacted} comm="{redacted}" exe="{redacted}
type=EXECVE msg=audit(1384889328.421:128620): argc={redacted} a0="{redacted}" a1="{redacted}" a2="{redacted}"
type=CWD msg=audit(1384889328.421:128620):  cwd="{redacted}"
type=PATH msg=audit(1384889328.421:128620): item=0 name="/{redacted}" inode={redacted} dev={redacted} mode={redacted} ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00
type=PATH msg=audit(1384889328.421:128620): item=1 name=(null) inode={redacted} dev={redacted} mode={redacted} ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00
```

How can I say I don't want type=PATH to be logged? Or any "type" for that matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 -a exclude,never -F msgtype=PATH
```

The [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) explains the other filters you can apply.

[libaudit.h](https://fedorahosted.org/audit/browser/trunk/lib/libaudit.h#L40) has the best list of types that I've found.

Comment: How do you exclude everything, except for the things you want